# How to webscrape the hidden content on website?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to websrcape some information on thw folowing website:https://entertainment.cathaypacific.com/catalog?template=movie&parent=%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1

However, there is a "show More" buttom on the bottom of the page.
How do I get all the information without clicking that buttom?

I would like the scrape all movies title,years, movie's length and its href links.
here is my code:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data1=[]
data2=[]

async def get_data():
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto("https://entertainment.cathaypacific.com/catalog?template=movie&parent=%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1", waitUntil="networkidle0")

    html = await page.content()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    titles = soup.find_all('a')
    for title in titles[7:]:
        data1.append(title.text)
    infs = soup.find_all("span",{"class" :"ng-star-inserted"})
    for inf in infs:
        data2.append(inf.text.strip())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_data())

data1_e = data1[0:-5][::2]
data1_o = data1[1:-5][::2]
data2_e = data2[0:-5][::2]
data2_o = data2[1:-5][::2]
    

d1 = pd.DataFrame(data1_o)
d2 = pd.DataFrame(data2_e)
d3 = pd.DataFrame(data2_o)

result = pd.concat([d1,d2,d3], axis=1,join='inner')
print(result)

df = pd.DataFrame(result).to_excel('HIHI.xlsx', index = False)
```

I can only get limited movies from the website, since there are a "show more" buttom.
How do I get the href links with the movies and more movies?

I know my code is very messy and I'm a beginner of coding, you are welcome to advise or enhance my code.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why don't you just use Selenium and click the button?

Comment: As this is a dynamic page, the content you're looking for probably isn't actually there beyond the button. It will. be generated when the button is clicked. I reccomend using something like Selenium instead

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use a proper library for this such as "selenium".

```
import selenium
# Using Chrome to access web
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# Open the website
driver.get("https://entertainment.cathaypacific.com/catalog?template=movie&parent=%E9%9B%BB%E5%BD%B1")
# Find button
more_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "showMore")
# Click login
more_button.click()
```

Unfortunately the "button" doesn't have an id so I've grabbed it using it's class "showMore" but that's not very reliable.

[Code from this tutorial.](https://towardsdatascience.com/controlling-the-web-with-python-6fceb22c5f08)

Comment: Sorry, i'm not quite understand. What should I do for the next?

Comment: Try following the tutorial I linked. You should have all the information you need.